# I can not get Wordpress to connect to my SMTP server

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, econnrefused

I am trying to get my Wordpress site (running on aiauto.cloud to send out email via my emailserver running in on server.cybxpert.com port 25251.

I have run GMASS SMTP Test Tool and it connects, and checked with Telnet - "Server Ready".

But ALL of the well-known plugins give me the same  "failure to connect".
I have tried
WP-Mail-SMTP, POST SMTP Mailer, SMTP Mailer, and FluentSMTP, all of them refuse to connect, while GMASS and Telnet both connect !!!!

Here is the Connection log from SMTP Mailer v1.1.6:

2023-07-31 14:06:35 Connection: opening to server.cybxpert.com:25251, timeout=300, options=array()
2023-07-31 14:06:36 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to server.cybxpert.com:25251 (Connection refused) [/home/aiaugdju/public_html/wp-includes/PHPMailer/SMTP.php line 389]
2023-07-31 14:06:36 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server

I have double and triple checked the username and password.
I have tried with and without TLS

I have been trying to get it working all day.
Any suggestions ?

PS
This is the SERVER info:

> OS: Linux server167.web-hosting.com
> 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.90.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 21 12:26:30 UTC 2023 x86_64 PHP version: 8.1.21 WordPress version: 6.2.2 WordPress
> multisite: No openssl: Available allow_url_fopen: Enabled
> stream_socket_client: Available fsockopen: Available

And this is from GMASS SMTP Tester:

```
Connected to smtp://server.cybxpert.com:25251/?starttls=when-available
<< 220 server.cybxpert.com ESMTP service ready
>> EHLO [172.31.11.248]
<< 250-server.cybxpert.com says hello
<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<< 250-PIPELINING
<< 250-CHUNKING
<< 250-8BITMIME
<< 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
<< 250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
<< 250-XACK
<< 250-SIZE 0
<< 250-VERP
<< 250-SMTPUTF8
<< 250 DSN
>> AUTH CRAM-MD5
<< 334 PDk2MzFBMUQ4QHNlcnZlci5jeWJ4cGVydC5jb20
>> YWRtaW5AY3lieHBlcnQuY29tIDhiYWFjZTRkZTRlYzAyNTFiMzRjNjU4ZWRmOWZmZTI5
<< 235 2.7.0 authentication succeeded
>> MAIL FROM:<admin@quizmaster.pro> SIZE=571
>> RCPT TO:<dave.chitchatmedia@gmail.com>
<< 250 2.1.0 MAIL ok
<< 250 2.1.5 <dave.chitchatmedia@gmail.com> ok
>> DATA
<< 354 send message
>> From: admin@quizmaster.pro
>> Date: Mon, 31 Jul 2023 12:59:34 퍍
>> Subject: SMTP test from server.cybxpert.com
>> Message-Id: <38KMYH1QLKU4.KX1VW3033MDM2@WIN-AUIR3RRGP88>
>> To: dave.chitchatmedia@gmail.com
>> MIME-Version: 1.0
>> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=-qbnKY3QwxFYSrq/lTyiamw=="
>>
>> --=-qbnKY3QwxFYSrq/lTyiamw==
>> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>>
>> Test message
>> --=-qbnKY3QwxFYSrq/lTyiamw==
>> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>> Content-Id: <38KMYH1QLKU4.41OSS1AA1OKI1@WIN-AUIR3RRGP88>
>>
>> <b>Test message</b>
>> --=-qbnKY3QwxFYSrq/lTyiamw==--
>> .
<< 250 2.6.0 message received
```

Comment: "Connection refused" means the client program (SMTP Mailer) was able to contact the server machine you mentioned, and that server machine had no server software listening on the port you specified. Double check `25251`. And, double check whether you're expected to use TLS.

Comment: Thanks for reply ... I have added the result from Gmass SMTP tester which shows connection and sending via port 25251

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because these plugins work with about 3 million other sites !!!  But it is not making sense :(